# ImageButton over action bar android

Tags: android

I want imagebutton over action bar in my app like this:

[image]

My xml code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="in.yumigo.yumigovendor.ui.activity.InvoiceActivity"
        android:id="@+id/invoice_recycler_view">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    <ImageButton
        android:elevation="2200dp"
        android:id="@+id/float_calendar"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        style="@style/CalendarFloating"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/calendar_144"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Obviously, the button is hidden under the actionbar like this:
[image]

How to achieve it?

Comment: are u using toolbar or old actionbar?

Comment: you need to customize your own action bar

Comment: I don't see any toolbar code here. Please provide full code

Comment: without custom action bar, is it not possible?

Comment: What do you mean by custom action bar? Android provided `toolbar` specially for high customization, Please go through toolbar examples.

Answer (score 0):

change your relative layout to **framelayout** or coordinator layout then give **margintop** to your image button this will do the trick

have a look at the layout below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.tcyonline.android.myapplication.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/ntn"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:elevation="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/calendar" />


    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />
</FrameLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: have already given the margin top, does not works with FrameLayout or CoordinatorLayout

Answer (score 0):

If you can place your right below the `ActionBar`, then try giving your imageButton a negative `marginTop`.

e.g. `android:marginTop="-16dp"`

You may also need to use `elevation` and/or `bringToFront` to bring your imageButton in front of `ActionBar`